# Getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I am creating an e-commerce website and while retrieving a product detail getting this error!

```
exports.getProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const prodId = req.params.productId;
  return Product.findById(prodId).then(([rows])=>{
    res.render('shop/product-detail', {
      product: rows[0],
      pageTitle: rows.title,
      path: '/products'
    });
  })
  .catch(err=> console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: It means that `findById` doesn't return a `Promise`

Comment: You have to check if `params` are valid before call `findById` function.

Comment: Thank you so much! Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The params need to be checked for validity before calling the findById function, because I did not checked this and faced this error.